# How to allow specific page in an iFrame - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iframe, cross-domain

We are working on a web project (ASP.NET Core 3.1). We have a requirement to allow to open *only a specific page* in an iframe from other origins. All other pages should not be accessible through iFrame.

We have tried a few ways as below:

1. We have tried to remove `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` from the header using middleware.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.OnStarting((state) =>
    {
        _headersToRemove.ForEach(header =>
        {
            if (context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(header))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Remove(header);
            }
        });

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }, null);            

    await next.Invoke(context);
}
```

But, didn't get server headers (X-Frame-Options) here in middleware.

2. We have used content security policy

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self' *.website.com" />
```

This works for the specified origin, however, it allows all the pages to be loaded in iframe.

3. We have tried to remove `X-Frame-Options` header from the `web.config` file

```
<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
```

4. We have tried to suppress `X-Frame-Options` header, but it allowed all the domains

```
public static void AddAntiForgery(this IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
  {                
      options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;                
      options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
      options.Cookie.Name = "_app";
      options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
      options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
  });
}
```

So, the question is, how we can allow only a specific page in an iframe from other domains?

**EDIT**

I have already enabled the CORS.

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have tried several different ways and come up with a solution.

First, need to remove `<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />` from web config file.

Second, add `X-Frame-Options` programmatically for all the requests expect page that needs to open in iFrame.

```
app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/controller/action"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        await next();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[EnableCors]` attribute only for the specific controller method instead of applying it globally: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#scope-rules-for-enablecors

Comment: Perhaps it's not CORS issue, I have already set `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` in web config file. But the issue is still persist

Comment: @DivyangDesai I don't understand what you mean by "perhaps not a CORS issue". You only want to allow cross-origin access for a specific page. That's CORS.
If you allow CORS globally, I will allow every method to be included in an iframe. That's not what you've asked for in your question

Comment: I think I didn't explain the question clearly. Yes, I want to allow a specific page from cross-domains, but in iFrame. And I have set xframe-options as same-origin only.